# Type Mismatch error when setting source data for a chart equal to an array

Tags: vba, excel

I need to populate an array with values from a range, then I want to use this array as the source data for a chart.  I've tried setting the array as variant and as long and neither seem to work.  Every time I try to run the code I get a type mismatch error at the line with .SetSourceData:=PlotRangeBar.  Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim XRangeBar As Range
Dim PlotRangeBar() As Variant
Dim PlotRange As Range

Set XRangeBar = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B" & DataStart & ":B" & DataEnd)
i = 0
For Row = DataStart To DataEnd
    If Cells(Row, UsedColTimesheet).FormulaR1C1 <> "0" And Cells(Row, UsedColTimesheet) <> vbNullString Then
        ReDim Preserve PlotRangeBar(i)
        PlotRangeBar(i) = Cells(Row, UsedColTimesheet).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .SetSourceData Source:=PlotRangeBar 'Error occurs here
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = XRangeBar
        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay)
        .ApplyLayout (1)
        .ChartTitle.Text = ResourceName & " - Hours per project"
        .Legend.Delete
        .ChartStyle = 18
        .ProtectSelection = True
    End With
```

I don't understand where the type mismatch comes from.  I would very much apreciate any insight, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetSourceData accepts a Range as the data type for the source parameter, not an array. This is confirmed in the MSDN documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196.aspx).

You'd need to include the data in a worksheet range, and use that as the source.